# BufferedImage byte array manipulation affects neighboring pixels

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to implement some low level filters in java. For that I have to be able to manipulate every individual pixel of the image. And I figured the best way would be to convert image to byte array and go from there.

I created a 2x2 image consisting of 4 completely red pixels. Then I read it into array and got a fairly accurate representation using following code:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
try {
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpeg"));
} catch (IOException e) { }

byte[] b = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

This is working as it should. I get this reading from the array.

```
0 0 -2  0 0 -2  0 0 -2  0 0 -2
```

These are RGB channels for each pixel. They are printed in reverse for some reason. B, G, R. You can see that pixels are red, because the byte for red channel is -2. (their unsigned value is thus 254).

Problem emerges as I change the values of these pixels in array and then try to convert that array back into image. for example, I change the first pixel to white:

```
-1 -1 -1  0 0 -2  0 0 -2  0 0 -2
```

for the conversion I use this code:

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("new_image.jpg"));
```

But this also affects the neighboring pixels. It should just set the first pixel to white and that is it. I have two images for comparison.

[image: Original image]

[image: Processed image]

*don't mind dotted rectangles in the bottom corner. I don't know where that came from when I was screenshoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

JPEG is a lossy format and it always (even at 100% quality) compresses the image and thus it loses some detail. Using .bpm or .png doesn't have this effect and works just as it should.

Comment: That should not gives the given image, something else happens here.

Comment: @Jean: that was the solution posted by the OP, I just moved it here to a wiki answer. Perhaps ping them under their question?

Comment: Yes that answer is correct, I didn't think too much... Of course this is due to lossly compression. Sorry guys.

Comment: You mean lossy, not lossless.